How to use react-markdown to render a Markdown file that is in a remote URL?

  If I have a remote Markdown file containing release information (history), which is typically maintained by a Product Manager, and I want to show an anchor within it when I click an element (like Release version number) in a React application, how do I do that? I couldn't find a specific example anywhere in the internet.
Regards,
Paddy
I tried searching on the Internet for an example to launch an anchored link to a Markdowm file URL using React Markdown
